# How to completely get rid of a partition?

Tags: partitioning

This partition is dedicated to Linux. It is about 250 GB. Since that time, I've decided not to use Linux anymore. So, I want to completely get rid of Linux and be able to use that space on my hard drive for things like video games, etc.

Is that something I can do without wiping the drive?

And please assume I'm an idiot, because I'm clueless with computers.

Comment: If you are clueless then maybe you should not be trying to delete partitions, get some help from a fiend.

Answer (score 0):

If you open *Disk Management* (`diskmgmt.msc`), you can find the partition, right-click and delete it. Then either reallocate the space to an existing drive using "Extend volume", or create a new drive.

https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/7-ways-to-open-disk-management-in-windows-10.html